# Android - How do I change button text to arraylist item

Tags: android, arrays, settext

I've got a grid of nine buttons and at the moment each one displays the numbers 1-9 as text and another button which will change the numbered buttons text to a different number from 1-9 when clicked. So basically it will appear to shuffle the buttons around but really its just changing the text. Or is it easier to just shuffle the buttons?

Can I put the numbers 1-9 into a string array to get the button text to change to an item from the array? And how do I make sure it uses all the numbers 1-9 once?

Comment: Yes :-) Do this and write some code, then as ka question if your stuck. Your last point you would get a random number between, 0-9 then add it to a list of used number, then get another random 0-9 an check it's not been used.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the Button text will be more easier and faster than realigning the buttons itself will be more complicated. to change the button text value use this. I think you know this.

```
Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbt);
    yourButton .setText(stringarrayvalue);
```

So use a ArrayList of buttons and change the value of buttons from it ..